# No such file or directory for serviceAccountKey.json

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

when i run this code

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

i get this error

```
File "C:\Users\olive\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
  File "C:\Users\olive\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\firebase_admin\credentials.py", line 83, in __init__
    with open(cert) as json_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serviceAccountKey.json'
```

The `serviceAccountKey.json` is located here

[image: the serviceAccountKey.json is located here]

Comment: Have you tried `Certificate("./venv/serviceAccountKey.json")` ? You can set the path in environment as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) and then just use `firebase_admin.initialize_app()` which might be a bit easier.

Comment: Hi, putting in ./venv worked, thanks alot !!

Comment: yeah, put it into a virtual env and try, it'll definitely work!